# Azure Relay - Hybrid connection reuse

Tags: azure, azure-hybrid-connections

Creating new HybridConnectionStream object like below, for every client request thread takes time (~3sec)

```
var client = new HybridConnectionClient(new Uri(String.Format("sb://{0}/{1}", relayConfiguration.Value.RelayNamespace, relayConfiguration.Value.ConnectionName)), tokenProvider);

-- (takes ~3 secs) 
HybridConnectionStream relayConnection= await client.CreateConnectionAsync();
```

Is there any way out to reuse/cache already established HybridConnectionStream to serve all future request of same client or possible to create pool of HybridConnectionStream to cater future client request faster.
Our implementation as follows:  
 Some user action on mobile app requires data from on premises DB, so the user action hits azure hosted service fabric api which in turn forward the request to specific azure relay hybrid connection then our custom, on premise hosted listener service pick the request & forward it to on premises web service to pick data
 Here the service fabric app creates **NEW** hybridconnection/hybridconnectionstream to establish connection with azure relay hybrid connection for each & every incoming user request  which is time consuming & we want to avoid new hybridconnection creation everytime  instead looking for options to cache & reuse already created costly hybridconnection or trying to create hybridconnection pool kind of thing.
 please advice if it is possible or suggest something else which is even better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We use hybrid connections between one of our App Services and one of several VMs. An Azure hybrid connection is kind of like a VPN. (You have to tilt your head and squint just right.)

> Within App Service, Hybrid Connections can be used to access application resources in other networks. Source: [Azure App Service Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections)

So I think you should look at a hybrid connection as something persistent. It's part of your network infrastructure, not something you need to create for each thread. I think the amount of time it takes to create a hybrid connection is in line with that kind of thinking.

Comment: Thanks for reply but My question is related to 'Azure Relay Hybrid Connections' not about 'Azure **App Service** Hybrid Connections'. <br/>

Comment: As an attempt to improve performance, Im proposing to use one common hybrid connection for all user's requests for on premises resource, in this case how to ensure the response received from hybridconnection is for the request sent since all user's request/response passes through common connection. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the HybridConnectionStream open and reuse it. Do not close it when you still need it. You can send multiple messages over a single stream. It is read / write so should not be a problem.